# Counting elements with certain word length in abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, enumerative-combinatorics

Given a (finite) abelian group $G = \langle S \mid R \rangle$, has the problem of counting the number of elements which can be expressed as a word (in $S$) of length $\leq k$ been studied? If so, where can I read more about it?

The question, rephrased: How big is the set $S_k$:
$$S_k = \{ g \in G \mid |g| \leq k\}$$
where $|g|$ is the minimal word size for $g$ in $S$?

Would it be simpler if we knew that $G$ is a $p$-group?

I am interested in cases where "analytical" solutions can be found, e.g. a generating function or a recurrence relation for $|S_k|$.

I think that this problem will be easy or hard depending on what $S$ is.

Comment: Just a remark: this is not trivial even for cyclic groups.

Comment: For sufficiently large $k$, $|S_k|$ will be a polynomial function of $k$; I believe this was first shown by Khovanskii http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1209944 , although there are now several proofs (as can be seen by browsing the followup literature).

Answer (score 2):

The papers of [Bela Bajnok](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Bajnok_B/0/1/0/all/0/1) and Ryan Matzke have some answers for you, and a good summary of what is known.